# What's the correct way to do a rotating log with python twisted?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, twisted

I'm using Twisted 14.0.2 and I was wondering what's the correct way of doing a rotating log file without blocking I/O?

Comment: Close and reopen the log file on SIGHUP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log files are pretty much inherently blocking things.  Eventually Twisted may integrate a non-blocking log consumer with an intelligent buffering policy, but that day is not here yet.  Good luck!